# Ensure a TD stays the same size as nested DIVs on Email

Tags: html, css, html-email

Trying to create a card-style layout for a certain section of my email newsletter, but for some reason, I cant get the container to match up to the size of the two nested divs.

The simplified code I'm essentially working with is below: (see the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mc2dqLzL/3/))

```
<table width="600px" bgcolor="#2075b9" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:#FFF;
                outline:1px solid #AAA;
                border-bottom:3px solid #BBB;
                padding:0px;
                margin:15px;
                overflow:hidden;
                box-sizing:border-box;">
                    <div style="display:inline-block; width:240px;" >example</div>
                    <div width="240px" style="display:inline-block;width:240px;">example</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, while the content divs themselves are 240px each, the style applied to the container div is larger than that (it fills the table minus the margin).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a **HTML-Email Newsletter**, you need to use the **old** (even deprecated -**for browsers**) HTML, so here is a snippet based on yours.

#### Snippet

```html
<table width="600" bgcolor="#2075b9" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #bbb; border-width:1px 1px 3px">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" width="240">
            example1
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="240">
          example2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As Dippas says, only use <table> when it comes to html email coding, mail clients dont support the use of <div>'s as framework

Comment: Isn't there some best practice about breaking up nested tables with divs?

Comment: best-practice no? see [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/guidelines/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to your main div

See [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mc2dqLzL/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply `display: inline-block;` to the container `div`. A `block` element take all the space possible from it's parent.

BUT : You're talking about Email. I would not recommend using all this `display` things because email clients doesn't all allow it. Take a look at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/. It's better to stick with old web css like table structure.